# R how to create a new column and populate values based on entries of another column

Tags: r, dplyr, case

I've a dataset which has countries in a column, and I intend creating anoda column for the region.
I used the code below using mutate and case_when,

```
    dput(head(internet))
structure(list(Entity = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"), Code = c("AFG", 
"AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG"), Year = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 
1993, 1994, 1995), Internet_Usage = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

dput(head(Middle_East_and_North_Africa))
structure(list(`c(...)` = c("Algeria", "Bahrain", "Egypt", "Iran", 
"Iraq", "Israel")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```r
internet_n <- internet %>%
  mutate(Region = case_when(Entity %in% toupper(Middle_East_and_North_Africa) ~ "Middle East and North Africa",
                               Entity %in% toupper(Latin_America_and_Caribbean) ~ "Latin America and Caribbean",
                               Entity %in% toupper(East_Asia_and_Pacific) ~ "East Asia and Pacific",
                               Entity %in% toupper(South_Asia) ~ "South Asia",
                               Entity %in% toupper(North_America) ~ "North America",
                               Entity %in% toupper(Europe_Central_Asia) ~ "Europe Central Asia"))
```

but the new column (Region) has NA all through as shown below

```
dput(head(internet_n))
structure(list(Entity = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"), Code = c("AFG", 
"AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG"), Year = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 
1993, 1994, 1995), Internet_Usage = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Region = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: `Error: object 'internet' not found`. After that, I'm going to guess that we'd next see `Error: object 'Middle_East_and_North_Africa' not found`, though I can't be certain.

Comment: Where is `internet` data?

Comment: Please don't share images of data. Instead share a copy-paste friendly version of your data so others can help. You can use `dput(head(internet))` for example.

Comment: Additionally, please don't spam the tags. The Stack tag-recommendation system is good but certainly imperfect; when asking (or reviewing) your questions, please double-check, that all tags are meaningful. Even if you eventually intend to visualize something in your data with the `ggplot2` package, there is nothing in your (pic of) data, code, or question that suggests you have even attempted any "plot" code. I'm editing it out for now, please check your questions in the future. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create new column based on another variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66923282/create-new-column-based-on-another-variable)

Comment: @r2evans , I've included the head of the internet as well as one of the regions, I've also removed the picture as suggested, thanks.

Comment: So, your Afghanistan rows return NA. What region is it in? You show us enough of `Middle_East_and_North_Africa` to see it's not there. Is it in a different region?

Comment: @GregorThomas, Yes it is in a different region, all codes shown are sneak of what I have here, I'm not sure I can post all of it on SO

Comment: Don't post all of it, just post the one relevant to your example. Your sample input has Afghanistan, so show us the region sample that has Afghanistan in it. Then we can run code on your sample data for just that region.

Comment: Why are you running `toupper` on just the regions though? That will turn `Afghanistan` into `AFGHANISTAN`. Either don't use `toupper` at all, or use it on both `Entity` and the region vectors.